# How to listen to a class change on Flutter's BuildContext.select()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am very new to Flutter, and have been trying to use the Provider package to handle state management.
Is is possible to listen to changes on a whole class with context.select()?

The simplified code is below.
I know the values are changing under the hood, but are not being reflected in the UI.

I also know that if I listen to each individual value on the class, it will reflect. But I was hopping for a way to get the change on the class as a whole.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final WageValues wageValues = context.select<ValuesModel, WageValues>(
      (values) => values.wageValues,
    );

    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Wage: ${roundToDecimals(wageValues.wage)}'),
        Text('Insurance Percent: ${wageValues.insurancePercent}'),
        Text('Insurance Sum: ${roundToDecimals(wageValues.insuranceSum)}'),
        Text('Wage Total: ${roundToDecimals(wageValues.wageTotal)}'),
        const WageForm(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class WageValues {
  double wage = 12;
  int insurancePercent = 30;

  double get insuranceSum => wage * insurancePercent * 0.01;
  double get wageTotal => wage + insuranceSum;
}

class ValuesModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final WageValues _wageValues = WageValues();

  WageValues get wageValues => _wageValues;

  void setWage(double wage) {
    _wageValues.wage = wage;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setInsurancePercent(int insurancePercent) {
    _wageValues.insurancePercent = insurancePercent;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package instead of `Provider` package for this code:

**home_page.dart**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getx_obs_class/src/controllers/checker_controller.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _rnd = Random();
    final _wv = valuesModel.wageValues;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Obx(() => Text('Wage: ${_wv.wage.toStringAsFixed(2)}')),
              Obx(() => Text('Insurance Percent: ${_wv.insurancePercent}%')),
              Obx(() => Text('Insurance Sum: ${_wv.insuranceSum.toStringAsFixed(2)}')),
              Obx(() => Text('Wage Total: ${_wv.wageTotal.toStringAsFixed(2)}')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.track_changes),
        onPressed: () {
          valuesModel
          ..setWage(_rnd.nextDouble() * 100)
          ..setInsurancePercent(_rnd.nextInt(100));
          print('\$${_wv.wage} : ${_wv.insurancePercent}%');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**checker_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class WageValues extends GetxController {
  var wage = 12.0.obs;
  var insurancePercent = 30.obs;

  double get insuranceSum => wage * insurancePercent.value * 0.01;
  double get wageTotal => wage.value + insuranceSum;
}

class ValuesModel {
  final WageValues _wageValues = Get.put(WageValues());

  WageValues get wageValues => _wageValues;

  void setWage(double wage) => _wageValues.wage.value = wage;
  void setInsurancePercent(int insurancePercent) => _wageValues.insurancePercent.value = insurancePercent;
}


final valuesModel = ValuesModel();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading through the Get docs and it seems an outstanding library. Will definetly be trying it out.